# Getting ajax loaded elements in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a chrome extension that accesses a web site in the background, gets an element from the loaded page and then changes the badge text according to that element.

So far I have this in background.js:

```
function updateIcon(text) {
    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({"text": text});
}

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
    $.get(link, function(data) {
        myText = $(data).filter("#myElement").html()
        updateIcon(myText);
    });
});
```

And this works perfect on my test.html page:

```
<html>
  <button id="myElement">Test</button>
</html>
```

But as I have recently found out, the reason it doesn't work on the page I intend to use it is because "myElement" is loaded via ajax and is not in the dom on pageload. Would there be any methods of getting that element even if it loads through ajax? Right now my code returns an "undefined" value.

Comment: You'll need to load the page in a in iframe or in an inactive tab and have a content script access its DOM. Alternatively, you can try inspecting the site code and reproduce its AJAX request manually.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I successfully reproduced the AJAX requests of the site.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I followed wOxxOm's advice and reproduced the site's AJAX requets and it worked. Thank you.